# Groovy HTTP ResponseParseException not found

Tags: java, json, http, grails, groovy

I am trying to make simple `GET` request using groovy HTTP request. I am expecting JSON response in this form:

```
{Records:[]}
```

So far I have done this in my code:

```
def getCountries(def cookies) {

    if (!cookies) {
        println("cookies list is empty!")
        return false
    }

    println("get countries, cookies list: ")
    println(cookies)

    try{

        def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://www.evisitor.hr/test_API/Rest/")
        http.request(GET, ContentType.JSON) {
            uri.path = "Htz/Country/RecordsAndTotalCount?psize=20&page=1&sort=NameNational%20desc"
            headers.Accept = 'application/json'
            headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
            String c = cookies.join(";")
            println("before appending in header: ")
            println(c)
            headers.'Set-Cookie' = c

            response.success = { respnse, reader ->
                String text = resp.entity.content.text
                println("text is: " + text)
                String contentType = resp.headers."Content-Type"
                println("content type is: " + contentType)
                if (contentType?.startsWith("application/json")) {
                    def json = JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
                    println(json)
                    println("1")
                }
                else {
                    println("2")
                }
            }

            response.failure = { resp, reader ->
                println "Failure response: ${resp.status}"
            }
        }



    }catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
        println("3")
        ex.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
        println("4")
        ex.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}
```

and I am always getting this response:

```
3
| Error groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: Not Found
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:500)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:390)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request$0.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$$EPpVE4fg.$tt__getCountries(EvisitorService.groovy:175)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$$DPpVE4fg.$tt__getCountries(Unknown Source)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService.$tt__getCountries(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$_getCountries_closure3$$EPpVE4fg.doCall(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:122)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$_getCountries_closure3.call(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$_getCountries_closure3.call(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:88)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$$EPpVE4fg.getCountries(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$$DPpVE4fg.getCountries(Unknown Source)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService.getCountries(EvisitorService.groovy)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$getCountries$0.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at com.manas.evisitor.EvisitorService$getCountries$0.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at com.manas.frontdesk.EvisitorController.testevisitor(EvisitorController.groovy:42)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
| Error Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
The current character read is '<' with an int value of 60
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
^
| Error     at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValueInternal(JsonParserCharArray.java:216)
| Error     at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValue(JsonParserCharArray.java:166)
| Error     at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeFromChars(JsonParserCharArray.java:45)
| Error     at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.parse(JsonParserCharArray.java:409)
| Error     at groovy.json.internal.BaseJsonParser.parse(BaseJsonParser.java:121)
| Error     at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(JsonSlurper.java:224)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseJSON(ParserRegistry.java:280)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1074)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:561)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
| Error     ... 113 more
done
```

I have googled and found out that it's problem related to groovy and this problem was not occurring before version 2.3.0, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704985/groovy-httpbuilder-producing-error-when-parsing-valid-json) post is saying.

I tried all answers and hints but none of them helped. What can I do to make my JSON parseable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to fetch data from incorrect URL, see [here](https://www.evisitor.hr//eVisitorWiki/Javno.Web-API.ashx). Should be:

```
https://www.evisitor.hr/eVisitorRhetos_API/Rest/Htz/Country/?psize=20&page=1
```

There's no `test_API` part. No page found results in `404` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095093/542270) answer explains the exception you get.

The script below (with changed URL) works - it gives `401` since I don't send authentication data:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1') 

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET

def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://www.evisitor.hr/eVisitorRhetos_API/Rest/")
http.request(GET, ContentType.JSON) {
    uri.path = "Htz/Country/?psize=20&page=1"
    headers.Accept = 'application/json'
    headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'

    response.success = { respnse, reader ->
        String text = resp.entity.content.text
        println("text is: " + text)
        String contentType = resp.headers."Content-Type"
        println("content type is: " + contentType)
        if (contentType?.startsWith("application/json")) {
            def json = JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
                println(json)
                println("1")
        } else {
            println("2")
        }
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
        println resp.status
    }
}
```

Also, the API is invalid, the requested response format - `Accept` header - is `application/json` and the result is returned in `HTML` - that's why `http-builder` fails - it expects different response format. The eliminate the exception change `response.failure` closure to:

```
{ resp ->
   println resp.status
}
```

eliminate the `reader` param - it will prevent http-builder from parsing the response automatically.

Comment: Yep, but that example is for production. I want to use test server to be sure everything works, and it says that for login i should use: 

https://www.evisitor.hr/testApi/Resources/AspNetFormsAuth/Authentication/Login

and it works fine, (I get auth cookies), and for other resources to use this:

 https://www.evisitor.hr/testApi/Rest/Htz/Country/ 

I tried your example and it works, but thanks anyways I will try to fix rest.

Comment: One more question, do you have any good reference for handling cookies using httpbuilder, getting and setting them, since I tried almost everything and I still get 401 code. Can I fetch them in string list or they must be exact Cookie objects ?

Comment: @Teemo, sorry I don't have, you can set cookies via a plain header. Long time ago I was just using `headers.Cookie = "some cookie header"`

Answer (score 0):

What your logs show is correct the url you are trying to hit gives 404 and a html error page that is not a valid json object

```
method :: GET
url    :: https://www.evisitor.hr/test_API/Rest/Htz/Country/RecordsAndTotalCount?psize=20&page=1&sort=NameNational%20desc
```

respons is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Server Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
                    <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```